# How to run this java class in command line in windows?

Tags: java

```
package com.test01;

public class test01 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

I think the java application launcher is very stupid.
I have point out the test01.class position:
  java -cp . test01(.class) 
but this doesn't works. It's very hard to use.

Comment: the -cp have to point out the dir which contain 'com'.....
so, this works:
java -cp ./bin/(contain com) com.test01.test01

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would run

```
java com.test01.test01
```

but having a class with the same name as a package is a *really* bad idea (as well as not following the Java naming conventions).

You'd need to run it with the relevant class on the classpath. For example, you *could* just compile it like this (from the "root" of your source tree):

```
javac -d . [path to source file]
java com.test01.test01
```

or if you've got your source organized appropriately already:

```
javac com\test01\test01.java
java com.test01.test01
```

Comment: OK, now that you have included the compiling part, I've deleted my answer for redundancy.

Comment: What if I have a lib folder and out folders?

Comment: @Kieveli: It's not clear what you mean. I suggest you ask a new, *detailed* question.

Answer (score 3):

You should be changing over to the base directory from where the classes start

java **-cp $CLASSPATH:.:** com.test01.test01

But naming a class "test01" is not a good naming convention.