# Java ProcessBuilder using periods in a string rather than slash when passing parameters

Tags: java, processbuilder, xterm

I'm trying to open an xterm terminal in Java, and run a Java file in it. Here's the Java code that is opening up the terminal:

```
Process p2 = new ProcessBuilder("xterm", "-hold", "-e", "java", "/home/harry/main.class").start();
```

xterm opens fine, but it's saying that it can't find the main class `home.harry.main.class`. I'm using slashes, but they're being changed to dots. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's just `main` (not `main.class`); `"java", "-cp", "/home/harry", "main"`

Comment: +Hovercraft Of Eels it is a fully qualified java class. Its just that xterm thinks that the slashes im giving it are periods. Please read my full question.

Comment: I agree with Elliot. What happens when you run "xterm -hold -e java /home/harry/main.class" on the command line(or shell)? The way to invoke a java command is to let it know where to find the classes (using -cp) and then to let it know which class you want to run (package+class-name).

Answer (score 1):

The mention of `xterm` is misleading.  The question (agreeing with [@elliott-frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) and [@user2533521](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2533521/user2533521)) is how to run a Java class on the command-line.  The full pathname and classfile name are two aspects which have to be separated.

Not quite a duplicate, these links can give some insight:

- [How to run this java class in command line in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314648/how-to-run-this-java-class-in-command-line-in-windows)
- [How to execute a java .class from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line)

That is (referring to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)):

- the "/home/harry" can be specified using the classpath `-cp` option (see *[Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)*).
- the ".class" suffix is not useful; only the class *name* is used (probably "main").